# Bijection from set of equivalence classes to $\mathbb R$

Tags: equivalence-relations

In $\mathbb R[X]$, define an equivalence relation ~ by $P_1$~$P_2$ if $P_1-P_2$ is divisible by X.

I have shown that $X$ is an equivalence relation.

Let $\mathscr Q$ denote the set of equivalence classes of ~ in $\mathbb R[X]$.

I now have to find an explicit bijection $\mathscr Q \to \mathbb R$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $ \ \rm x\mid p\!-\!q\!\iff\! p\equiv q\pmod{\! x}.\, $ $\rm\, p(x)\equiv p(0)\pmod{\! x},\,$ so $\rm\ p\sim q\!\iff\! p(0) = q(0).$

So the class of $\rm\,p\,$ consists of every polynomial with the same constant term $\rm\,p(0).\,$ A natural choice of representative is the "simplest" (lowest degree) element, i.e. the constant polynomial $\rm\,p(0).$

**Remark** $ $ If perchance you already know about quotient rings and evaluation homomorphisms of polynomial rings then you should examine this problem from that perspective, noting that $\rm\,p(0)\,$ is the result of applying the evaluation hom $\rm\,x\mapsto 0\,$ to $\rm\,p(x).$ Then, applying the First Isomorphism Theorem lifts our set-theoretic isomorphism to a ring-theoretic isomorphism $\,\Bbb R[x]/(x)\cong \Bbb R$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Define a map

$$\phi:\Bbb R[x]\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;\phi(p(x)):=p(0)$$

The nicest thing of the above is that $\;\phi\;$ is a ring homomorphism...

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're doing there. Could you try and explain it a bit more?

Comment: Well, check the relation you define actually means $$\;P_1\sim    P_2\iff x\mid(P_1-P_2)\iff P_1(x)-P_2(x)=xQ(x)\iff P_1(0)=P_2(0)\;$$ Hmm...have you studied already algebraic structures? Groups , rings...?

Comment: DonAntonio: I think that the term "ring homomorphism" might be more confusing than helpful in this context.

Comment: "Ant Onion", @AsafKaragila ?? Anyway, I think you may be right if the OP hasn't yet covered that, and I think it may be he hasn't.

Comment: We have studied groups and rings (although in  a different module). But we haven't come across the term homomorphism before.

Comment: Uh? Then you're beginning to study that thing, or you haven't *really* studied them...Anywaym Asaf's answer greatly complements my answer and, in fact, shows you the way to prove what you want without rings and homomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

We have $P_1\sim P_2\iff x|(P_1-P_2)\iff \exists Q$ such that $P_1(x)=xQ(x)+P_2$
and by the Euclidean division we have
$$P_1(x)=xQ(x)+P_1(0)$$
hence
$$P_1\sim P_1(0)$$
Can you see now the bijection?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint for DonAntonio's hint:

Note that if $f\sim g$ then $f(0)=g(0)$. Use this to prove that the map $[f]/\sim\mapsto f(0)$ is well-defined, and it is a bijection.